# php/html Why can't I echo a variable date in a date input field?

Tags: php, html, date, datetime, datepicker

I try to show a standard date as value in my date type input field. For some reason they way I thought it would work doesn't work, already searched on google and stackoverflow for any solutions but couldn't  really find anything. Maybe you guys have an idea? It is now like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UwXj.jpg) , and I want to have it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo2aN.jpg).

My code:

```
<?php $date = "1996-06-25";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date)); ?>                
<input type="date" name="date" value="<?php echo date($newDate);?>">
```

Comment: you just need to echo `$newDate`

Comment: Already tried it without the date around $newdate but doesnt work, it keeps giving me dd-mm-jjjj

Comment: Already changed it, I get the dates in the format Y-M-D but my question was how to get them into the input field, I understand how to set them in order.

Comment: "Getting them into the input field" is done by just `echo`ing them. So what is the real problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to change the date format, so try following

```
<?php $date = "1996-06-25";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)); ?>                
<input type="date" name="date" value="<?php echo $newDate;?>">
```

**Edited**

Your current date format is not correct that's why it does not working.

@AniketSahrawat Thank you for letting me know. I modified my answer after your comment

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the date format, but thanks for your answer, It still doesnt show the date in the input field

Comment: @J.Ende Can you copy paste same script because it is working on my side. I have checked it

Comment: You correct it is working when I copy it, that was weird, thanks mate ;)

Comment: Ye I will do that, it takes time to mark it green:)

Comment: If your date comes from database, like mine, let the strtotime fuction out.

Answer (score 5):

The date format is wrong, try this out :

```
<?php

$date = "25-06-1996";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)); ?>                
<input type="date" name="date" value="<?php echo $newDate; ?>">
```

**Edit**

Here's the proof that it works

[image]

The format like I said should be `Y-m-d`

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the date format, but thanks for your answer, It still doesnt show the date in the input field

Comment: @J.Ende I believe you down voted this answer. The format you are using is wrong. It should be `Y-m-d`

Comment: Only the second line is right, the first would work either way and the `date()` function in the last line does nothing.

Comment: Yes, don't know if he added those line to give us an example, or that's he's real code, I'll fix that in my answer

Comment: With the modified code by the OP, all that is needed is `echo $date;` :-)

Comment: I use a variable out of a database that has this non europian date format

Comment: Yes you should try it before doing any casts ... less functions, less code, more speed :)